# Python 3 simple HTTP server with GET functional

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver

I can't find any Python code for the equivalent of

```
python -m http.server port --bind addr --directory dir
```

So I need basically a working server class that process at least [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) requests. Most of the things I found on Google were either an HTTP server with some special needs or something like that, where you need to code the response behaviour be yourself:

```python
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

All that I need is a default working skeleton of a Python HTTP server, where you can provide address, port and directory, and it would normally process GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I ended up with:

```
# python -m http.server 8000 --directory ./my_dir

from http.server import HTTPServer as BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import os


class HTTPHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    """This handler uses server.base_path instead of always using os.getcwd()"""

    def translate_path(self, path):
        path = SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.translate_path(self, path)
        relpath = os.path.relpath(path, os.getcwd())
        fullpath = os.path.join(self.server.base_path, relpath)
        return fullpath


class HTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer):
    """The main server, you pass in base_path which is the path you want to serve requests from"""

    def __init__(self, base_path, server_address, RequestHandlerClass=HTTPHandler):
        self.base_path = base_path
        BaseHTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)


web_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'my_dir')
httpd = HTTPServer(web_dir, ("", 8000))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

A simple HTTP server that handles GET requests with, working with a certain directory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` to, well, handle the requests:

```py
class HTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """HTTP request handler with additional properties and functions."""

     def do_GET(self):
        """handle GET requests."""
        # Do stuff.
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But what code should be in this method to process simplest GET request, as for example apache2 doing it for default?

Comment: That entirely depends on *what* you want the method / web server to do.

Comment: I already wrote. I want simple HTTP server. So I can browse directories and view web-pages with css and images. Means on GET request I will get headers with file body. The command I mentioned in the begging is working perfectly but I need code-based solution

Answer (score -3):

Use the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests

# The required first parameter of the 'get' method is the 'url'(instead of get you can use any other http type, as needed):

r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089846/python-3-simple-http-get-functional')

# You can print many other things as well such as content, text and so on
print(r.status_code)
```

Check [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: because I need a carcass for http server, not client